# Create cast as a non-superuser user with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function, casting

I have a specific need to create a new cast in postgresql 9.6:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION boolean_to_float(b boolean) RETURNS float AS $$
SELECT b::int::float;$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
DROP CAST IF EXISTS (boolean as float);
CREATE CAST (boolean AS float) WITH FUNCTION boolean_to_float(boolean) ;
```

Unfortunately, I got the following response:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of type boolean or type double precision
```

The database is owned by the user I am using. Is it possible to force the `DROP/CREATE CAST` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says: you have to connect as user `postgres` in order to do that.